# RVM is loaded first in $PATH

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm working on developing contributing to [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Rainforest) and as part of that, I've added my development directory `bin` to my `$PATH`. I've done this by modifying my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=/Users/ash/Desktop/Rainforest/CocoaPods/bin:$PATH
```

And I expected everything would work. But when I try and invoke the `pod` command, I get an error that seems to indicate that it's trying to load the gem from somewhere else.

```
pod
/Users/ash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 120 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/ash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/ash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Hrm. So I `echo $PATH` to see what's up:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/ash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/ash/Desktop/Rainforest/CocoaPods/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ash/.rvm/bin
```

And there is a bunch of RVM stuff ahead of the directory that I added, even though there is nothing in `.zshrc`, `.profile`, or even things like `.bashrc` to indicate what's going on.

I've tried looking through all the different files that could modify the `$PATH` variable, with no luck. It seems like [someone else](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2370) is having this problem, but it's related to git pre-commit hooks, which I don't have. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pre-pending your extra path to `$PATH` before RVM is adding it's own paths. You should move your path after any rvm setup is done in your ZSH configs. Somewhere you will find something like the following:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

You should perform your actions after this instead of before.

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH=/Users/ash/Desktop/Rainforest/CocoaPods/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Yes, I found it in both `.zlogin` and `.bash_profile`. I'll update them and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me. Looks like `.zprofile` was being loaded *after* `.zshrc`. Thanks Kyle!

Answer (score 2):

If you're on OS X (and possibly Linux), you can modify your `/etc/paths` file to explicitly set what's in `$PATH`.

```
~$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~$
```

Looks like this should work for zsh. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25407

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround –not the solution to your real problem which I can’t help you with as I don’t use RVM– would be to uninstall the gems from your RVM installation, that way your shell will no longer find the bin in any of those RVM locations.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the RVM ruby for your work with CocoaPods:

```
rvm use system
```

to get back to rvm controlled ruby:

```
rvm use ruby
```